# How long does Signal keep the keys for out-of-order messages?

Tags: key-management, protocols, signal

I was reading the Signal protocol on how it handles out-of-order messages.  What if those messages never arrived, does Signal keep the keys forever or are the keys deleted as soon as a new session is started?

https://signal.org/docs/specifications/doubleratchet/

> 2.6. Out-of-order messages
>
> The Double Ratchet handles lost or out-of-order messages by including in each message header the
> message's number in the sending chain (N=0,1,2,...) and the length
> (number of message keys) in the previous sending chain (PN). This
> enables the recipient to advance to the relevant message key while
> storing skipped message keys in case the skipped messages arrive
> later.
>
> On receiving a message, if a DH ratchet step is triggered then the
> received PN minus the length of the current receiving chain is the
> number of skipped messages in that receiving chain. The received N is
> the number of skipped messages in the new receiving chain (i.e. the
> chain after the DH ratchet).
>
> If a DH ratchet step isn't triggered, then the received N minus the
> length of the receiving chain is the number of skipped messages in
> that chain.
>
> For example, consider the message sequence from the previous section
> when messages B2 and B3 are skipped. Message B4 will trigger Alice's
> DH ratchet step (instead of B3). Message B4 will have PN=2 and N=1. On
> receiving B4 Alice will have a receiving chain of length 1 (B1), so
> Alice will store message keys for B2 and B3 so they can be decrypted
> if they arrive later:

Comment: Looking at the implementation details in section 3 of the Double Ratchet Protocol whitepaper that you referenced, it seems as through keys for skipped messages persist for as least as long as the client is running.  However, there is a limit to the *number* of keys that the client will store - see information about MKSKIPPED in section 3.2.

Comment: I looked through the code. There is a MAX_SKIP constant controlling the number of out-of-order messages. From section 3.1   A MAX_SKIP constant also needs to be defined. This specifies the maximum number of message keys that can be skipped in a single chain. It should be set high enough to tolerate routine lost or delayed messages, but low enough that a malicious sender can't trigger excessive recipient computation.